# MVC: Using Mapping to change the model.SomeProperty type used in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Enum for some base data in database, including the data of Gender. For example Man `id`  is 10 and woman is 11.
I use **EF**.
In `User` entity I will use this Gender `Id`.
I will use User entity as **model** for **View**.
My approach is using join in MVC **controller** not in **db**.
I have to show search result for users in my view. If I use the User model, the result will show the Id of gender, and it's not OK. Since the type of Id and Title are not the same. So It's not possible to use the LINQ and replace the Id with Title.
How can I Set the Gender Title in result?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Automapper and view-model for resolving the issue. But I have installed Automapper 5.0.0.0.
Also I defined a View-Model that is same as main entity but Gender type. in view model the gender is string.

```
        var Data= Search(user);  //get search result using any approach, maybe a service or etc

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<User, VM_User>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.GENDER, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => u.GENDER == 10 ? "Male" : "Female")));


        List<VM_User> users = new List<VM_User>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
        {
            users.Add(config.CreateMapper().Map<VM_User>(Data[i]));
        }
```

and then I used the users as search result in view.
Also, I could forget using the third party (AutoMapper) and forexample have:

```
   var result = Data.Select(x => new VM_User
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Code = x.Code,
            Gender = x.Gender == 10 ? "Male" : "Female"
        }).ToList();
```

But it's useful if I'm sure the Entity properties will not change during coding.

Comment: If any other way, Please share it :)